# Is it possible to call NET CORE microservises without ControllerBase directly by endpoint?

Tags: .net-core, microservices, endpoint

Long way is inserting meaningful microservices code as derived of ControllerBase class, adding various attributes like HttpGet and Authorize. Then place to Configure method something like app.UseMVC or app.UseRouting and all will be working fine.
But if we have service, registered for example as

```
services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
```

is it possible call it directly by http://localhost:5000/ ?
if, of course, we have right configuration something similar

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet ("/", async context =>
            {
                await new WeatherForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Yes of course. Why didn't you just try it?
You would need to resolve the dependency "manually" by calling `context.RequestServices.GetService<WeatherForecastService>()`

Comment: working fine.             app.Map("/WeatherApi", App =>
            {
                App.Run((context =>
                {
                    return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        context.RequestServices.GetService<WeatherForecastService>().GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now), Formatting.Indented));
                }));
            });